# Reliability of self pressurization of propellant tanks for liquid engines

Tags: rockets, pressure

In a cryogenic propellant tank, the liquid always continuously changes into gas which pressurizes the tank. To pressurize the tank more we can run the liquid through the pipes along the outer wall and because of heat transfer the temperature of liquid increases and it changes into gas, which is known as self-pressurizing. This mechanism is mostly used for pressure fed systems.

How much can we rely on self-pressurizing, while we do it for the tanks in the rockets?

Is it better to use external tanks than self-pressurizing to pressurize the cryogenic propellant tanks in the rockets?

Will it lead to [flashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_evaporation) of the stored cryogenic liquid?

Comment: Do any real space launch boosters use this?

Comment: It is not only the reliability, it is also the question if the pressure is sufficient for the turbo pumps to work at full flow without cavitation and at nominal injection pressure.

Comment: A quick calculation would reveal the difficulties of this process from a operational stand point than from the perspective of reliability. The quantity of liquid transforming into high pressure gas(note this will lead to high density) will be enormous as the ullage volume keeps increasing with time.